# Pass value from view to Controller without querystring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having `index` method to list all students. Now I am adding search in the index with one `text_field_tag`. My function is working but the search value is showing as query string in the url. I don't want this.

My view code:

```
<p>
  <%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    Find by name: <%= text_field_tag :search %>
    <%= submit_tag  "Search", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

My controller code is

```
  def index
    searchString = params[:search]
    if searchString
      @students = Student.where("LastName like ?", "%#{searchString}%").paginate(:page => params[:page])
    else
    @students = Student.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

My current url look like below:

```
http://localhost:3000/students?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=A
```

I just need like `/students`. Please suggest the best practice

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `POST` request instead of `GET`. In order to accomplish that, change your `form_tag` from:

```
<%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'post' do %>
```

**What could possibly go wrong...**

*As @carlosramireziii mentioned, answering this question, requires a bit more work (and he is absolutely right!), so - there is update*

**1. Custom routes**

If you are configuring your routes on your own, one of ways proceeding with this is to add a route, that will properly accept your requests. Take a look at *config/routes.rb*:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match '/students', controller: :students, action: :index, via: [:get, :post]

  # other definitions
end
```

Definition like this will create following route for you:

```
students GET|POST /students(.:format)     students#index
```

This will make your new `POST` request nicely fall into `students#index`, generating expected result. **However**, if you are defining your routes via `resources` it's not that easy change. This leads us to...

**2. Modifying standard `resources` routes**

If routes for students are defined as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :students

  # other definitions
end
```

the following routes are registered:

```
    students GET    /students(.:format)          students#index
             POST   /students(.:format)          students#create
 new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)      students#new
edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format) students#edit
     student GET    /students/:id(.:format)      students#show
             PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
             PUT    /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
             DELETE /students/:id(.:format)      students#destroy
```

This indicates, the `POST` request falls into `students#create`. In order to make it work, you need to change the `create` action, to something like:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  # code omitted

  def create
    if params.include?('search')
      @students = Student.where("LastName like ?", "%#{searchString}%").paginate(:page => params[:page])
      render :index
    else
      # your current code from create action
    end
  end
end
```

While this will work, it is **not recommended** to do it this way. The `create` action does two things now, which is considered a bad pattern (or bad smell at least), and it is error prone.

So, what can we do?

**Making `search` the right way**

**1. Custom `search` route**

Define custom [collection route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :students do
    collection do
      post :search
    end
  end

  # other definitions
end
```

This registers following routes:

```
search_students POST   /students/search(.:format)   students#search
       students GET    /students(.:format)          students#index
                POST   /students(.:format)          students#create
    new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)      students#new
   edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format) students#edit
        student GET    /students/:id(.:format)      students#show
                PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
                PUT    /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
                DELETE /students/:id(.:format)      students#destroy
```

You need to change your `form_tag` as follows:

```
<%= form_tag search_students_path, :method => 'post' do %>
```

And add `search` action to `StudentsController`:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  # code omitted

  def search
    @students = Student.where("LastName like ?", "%#{searchString}%").paginate(:page => params[:page])
    # If you don't want to create separate template for `search`,
    # you can try  to reuse your `index` template with
    # render :index
  end
end
```

**2. Use `students#index` with params passed in URL**

This approach is more REST-y, and it makes it available to pass the whole URL to someone else, so the another person is able to see exactly the same result of filtering, which is impossible with `params` "hidden" in `POST` request.

I hope I've covered all possibilities. If you have any questions - I'm more than happy to answer!

Good luck!

Comment: @Pawel That is the right line of thinking, but if you make a POST to the `students_path`, you'll actually now be routing to the create action, not the index action. You'll need to make further changes to make this fully correct. Definitely the on the right track though!

Comment: @carlosramireziii You are absolutely right! I've updated the answer. This problem requires more explanation regarding the possible ways. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent answer! You enumerated all the possibilities quite nicely. Great work.